# How to add yii2 widget to <th>?

Tags: php, yii2

I want to add a yii2 widget to the :

```
        <th colspan="3">
            <?= $full_meeting->field($full_meeting_form->emitent, 'prefix')->textInput(['autofocus' => true, 'readonly' => true])->label($full_meeting_form->emitent->getColumns()['prefix']) ?>
        </th>
```

But as a result, it doesn't work the way I wanted it to. Text is overlaid with the widget text field

What could this have to do with?

Comment: Give some width ot th? Can you show screen?I don't get your problem at all

Comment: Yes, I tried to work with align, it did not work. Problem - https://ibb.co/KGr3LFG

Comment: inspect html and give 100% width to the element (may be widget container)